# Limit Visual Studio deployment to master branch only

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-devops

I want to limit the deployment of a data model to an Azure analysis service to only the master branch. How can I configure that? I'm using Azure DevOps as a remote repository.

Comment: I am not sure If I understand the question. Do you want to limit the commit on your master branch? If yes, then you could lock the branch on azure devops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/lock-branches?view=azure-devops . If you want your pipeline only to get triggered on specific branch, you should define your build triggers. https://medium.com/@geralexgr/build-triggers-on-azure-devops-pipelines-65729db8df50

Comment: Hmm no why should one do that? Isn't it useless to have branches without a commit? And i dont think its the second either. 
I will try to explain in more detail: In visual studio using the deployment properties of a project you can deploy it to a Deployment Server. What i want to do is limit this deploy option only to the master branch of the repository. 
So a possible way i think would be to delete from all branches the deployment property from the project. What i want to know if there a better option for that